# Random number Generation with Seed

Tags: c#, random, .net-4.5

If I am using the Random class in .Net(4.5) and I am always using the same seed to generate 1000 numbers is there a chance that on a different machine (with diff chipset / number of cores, etc) that my 1000 numbers could be different? I don't see how that could be, but was told by one of my colleagues that we need to be aware that they could be. The testing I have done seems to always be consistent. Just concerned that I could have a scenario where I could get different numbers.  I could understand it being different if I was trying to parallize the generation or something.

```
int seed = 99;
var random = new Random(seed);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   random.Next();
```

Comment: You set is not random if you're using the same seed each time.  If you want a static pseudo-random sequence just generate it once and hard-code it.

Comment: @DStanley Consider, for example, that you log the seed used to generate random numbers in a prod environment.  Can you be sure to get the same sequence in a development environment when using that same seed to try to replicate a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Between different PCs running the same framework sounds unlikely (meaning: you can reasonably expect the same sequences) - but MS do reserve the right to change the implementation. MSDN states:

> The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class is not guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, your application code should not assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.

So: if you need a stronger guarantee: use your own PRNG implementation. There are plenty of such to choose from.

Comment: +1. I'd not be surprised if one day `Rand` will behave as random per-AppDomain (similar to new option for `String.GetHashCode()` - [UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152924.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

According to this link, you will get the same sequence in all cases for **.Net 4.5**  Not sure if that applies to different versions of .Net framework (agreeing with previous answer).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx)

"Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers."